# mysql between but not equal

Tags: mysql

i have an query that returns values that are between 2 dates. The problem is that it returns the result even if the value is equal. Here is my query

```
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("Select * FROM tbl_rezervari tr 

                where (:start BETWEEN tr.start AND tr.end or :end BETWEEN tr.start AND tr.end)"); 

                $stmt->bindParam(":start",$startDate);
                $stmt->bindParam(":end",$endDate);
                $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BETWEEN` is an inclusive range of values(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).

If you don't want the values to be included in the range you may have to do it long hand...

```
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("Select * FROM tbl_rezervari tr 
         where ((:start > tr.start AND :start < tr.end) 
             or (:end > tr.start AND :end < tr.end))");
```

Comment: This answer works with date, datetime, and other kinds of numeric datatype. It is also more flexible because `>=` or/and `<=` could be used if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. Between And means [a,b] including a and b.

So if you want to exclude either a or b just make it minus 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already - the `between` operator is inclusive and thus includes the start and end dates in the range - you could however modify the query to `adddate` and `subdate` as below

```
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("select * from tbl_rezervari tr
    where ( 
    :start between adddate( tr.start, interval 1 day ) and subdate( tr.end, interval 1 day ) 
    or 
    :end between adddate( tr.start, interval 1 day ) and subdate( tr.end, interval 1 day ) 
    )");
```